# Inverse of symmetric tridiagonal block Toeplitz matrix

Tags: inverse, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

There is a triagonal block matrix $M$ of form:

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B^T & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
B & A & B^T & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & B & A & B^T & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & B & A 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $A, B$ are real-valued square matrices of the same size.

Also, $A$ is positive definite and symmetric. Later makes $M$ symmetric as well.

My interest is in closed-form solution for elements of $M^{-1}$.

From "Explicit inverses of some tridiagonal matrices" C.M. da Fonseca, J. Petronilho, I am aware of the closed-form solution for tridiagonal toeplitz matrix of form:

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
c & a & b & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c & a & b & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & c & a 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a, b, c$ - scalars.

$$
(T^{-1})_{ij} = \begin{cases}
(-1)^{i+j}\frac{b^{j-i}}{\left(\sqrt{bc}\right)^{j-i+1}}\frac{U_{i-1}(d)U_{n-j}(d)}{U_{n}(d)} \quad \text{if} \quad i \le j \\
(-1)^{i+j}\frac{c^{i-j}}{\left(\sqrt{bc}\right)^{i-j+1}}\frac{U_{j-1}(d)U_{n-i}(d)}{U_{n}(d)} \quad \text{if} \quad i \gt j
\end{cases}
$$
where $d = \frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}$, $U_{k}(x)$ - Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind.

Don't see a way to extend it to block matrices though. Does anybody know how it can be done? or any alternative way?

Comment: This [review article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244450365_A_Review_on_the_Inverse_of_Symmetric_Tridiagonal_and_Block_Tridiagonal_Matrices) seems to do something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extended search, found an [article](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1358&context=ecetr) "Numerically Stable Algorithms for Inversion of Block Tridiagonal and Banded Matrices" that gives direct algorithm for even more general problem.

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & -B_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
-B_1^T & A_2 & -B_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & -B_2^T & A_3 & -B_3 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & A_N 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where all $A_i$ are symmetric, all $B_i$ are non-singular.

Then, symmetry of $M$, as a whole, is exploited to get decomposition $(M^{-1})_{ij}=U_iV_j^T,\quad j \ge i$.

Note, when inverse of a symmetric matrix exists (and we assume it does) it should be symmetric as well.

$U$ and $V$ are given recursively:

$$
U_1 = I, \quad U_2=B_1^{-1}A_1\\
U_{i+1}=B_i^{-1}(A_iU_i-B^T_{i-1}U_{i-1}),\quad i=2,...,N-1\\
V_N^T=(A_NU_N-B_{N-1}^TU_{N-1}^T)^{-1}, \quad V_{N-1}^T=V_N^TA_NB_{N-1}^{-1}\\
V_i^T=(V_{i+1}^TA_{i+1}-V_{i+2}^TB_{i+1}^T)B_i^{-1}, \quad i=N-2,...,1
$$

Under constraints, that all $A_i$ are equal, all $B_i$ are equal, and $B=B^T$ (which I missed when posting original question!) equations become even simpler:

$$
U_1 = I, \quad U_2 = B^{-1}A \\
U_{i+1} = B^{-1}AU_i - U_{i-1},\quad i=2,...,N-1\\
V_N^T=(AU_N-BU_{N-1}^T)^{-1}, \quad V_{N-1}^T=V_N^TAB^{-1}\\
V_i^T=V_{i+1}^TAB^{-1}-V_{i+2}^T, \quad i=N-2,...,1
$$